# Windows 8.1 Pro Can't Boot

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

I have had Windows 8.1 for a while and all of a sudden I tried to boot my laptop and it had this screen:

[image: SCreenshot]

What can I do to fix this?

I have tried to run both 64 bit and 32 bit installation discs of the Operating System. I do not have access to any other drives.

I have tried taking my RAM out and cleaning it and the same for my hard drive. All of it to no avail.

Comment: Perhaps start by doing what it suggests?  As-is this question is way too broad and shows no research effort. Voting to close.

Comment: I have done plenty of research as nothing is relevant to my situation. I have done what it says and that doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't guess what you have tried, nor what the results were. Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: PS [0xc00000e9 = "STATUS_UNEXPECTED_IO_ERROR"](http://errlookup.azurewebsites.net/?err=0xc00000e9), so that points to a corrupted file system and/or a faulty hard drive.

Comment: By "Tried to run", do you mean the system doesn't boot onto the drive, or you're not doing anything once it boots?. ^ says HDD problem, and this guy knows his stuff, so try running `chkdsk` if you can get into the recovery environment (the disc). If you can't, BIOS tinkering!

Comment: Basically I tried to start my laptop. The windows logo appears, then instead of the Loading Circle consisting of dots, it says "Starting Automatic Repair" then gives me the screen posted in the question

Comment: I don't know how to get into the recovery environment

Comment: Insert the installation disc (the correct 32/64 bit architecture). If the system boots onto it automatically, then you can run a check.

Comment: If you hit F8 you would go into `Windows RE` but its very likely a system file is corrupt which means your options are limited to using the `Refresh` or `Reset` option to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On many systems, the default BIOS setting is to boot the the HDD first, only booting to the Optical Drive if there is no boot image on the HDD. In your case, there *is* a boot image on the HDD. Even though it's corrupted, your system is probably trying to boot to it.

In order to run the installation disc, you'll to boot to that drive. You can achieve this, without tinkering in the BIOS, by using the correct shortcut-key for the "Boot Menu". Typically, this is the `F12` key, but it varies based on your Motherboard. You'd press this as soon as your computer turns on. (Or, repeatedly press it after the computer turns on, until the menu appears). This has to be done before the Windows logo would normally show up.

Once you've reached the boot menu, it should give you a list of available hardware you can attempt to boot from. Choose the one that represents the optical drive you have your disc in.

It should then boot to the disc, making the HDD error irrelevant. Follow the prompts on the disc to attempt a repair.

Comment: Look at my previous question posted in which no one can answer apparently. The disc won't even continue after the disc's windows logo is gone